# How to pass an argument over a GoBackCommand in a Windows Store App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I want to pass an argument over to the previous page I visited when using a Binding GoBackCommand in the NavigationHelper.

**The Back button in XAML**

```
<Button x:Name="backButton"
                    Margin="39,59,39,0"
                    Command="{Binding NavigationHelper.GoBackCommand, ElementName=pageRoot}"
                    Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    AutomationProperties.Name="Back"
                    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="BackButton"
                    AutomationProperties.ItemType="Navigation Button"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsBackEnabled}"/>
```

I want to pass the argument similar to when I trigger an EventHandler and navigate forward, e.g

**C# Code Behind**

Send the argument

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string myArg = "Hello";
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(AnotherPage), myArg);
}
```

And retrieve it

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
     string myParam = e.Parameter.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution although there is probably a better way to do this

**C# Code Behind**

In your Page with the GoBackCommand, declare a GoBack method:

```
private void GoBack()
{
    string myArg = "Hello";
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(AnotherPage), myArg);
}
```

Then in your Page constructor just set the GoBackCommand to your GoBack method:

```
public MyPage()
{
     this.InitializeComponent();
     this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
     this.navigationHelper.LoadState += navigationHelper_LoadState;
     this.navigationHelper.SaveState += navigationHelper_SaveState;
     this.navigationHelper.GoBackCommand = new RelayCommand(GoBack);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CommandParameter` in your `XAML` to do that.

```
<Button x:Name="backButton"
                    Margin="39,59,39,0"
                    Command="{Binding NavigationHelper.GoBackCommand, ElementName=pageRoot}"
                    CommandParameter="This is my parameter"
                    Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    AutomationProperties.Name="Back"
                    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="BackButton"
                    AutomationProperties.ItemType="Navigation Button"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsBackEnabled}"/>
```

Comment: Brilliant! So where do I handle the parameter on the previous page?

Comment: Have a look at this http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2012/11/passing-eventargs-to-winrt.html